# Android - Images showing at different sizes on different devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-imageview, android-image

I am coming from the world of `iOS` so bear with me. I am getting a little confused about image scaling and why my images are appearing different sizes on different devices.

My app uses a large background image and in the middle are placed a number of other images in a stacked order. They are placed in a colored area which is part of the background image.

[image]

When viewing my layout  in the `Graphical View` different phones will show the individual tile images at different sizes. Sometimes they will all be contained within the dark grey background block and sometimes they overflow. Sometimes they are too small.

I am creating my background image:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backgroundImageView"
            android:layout_width="1000dp"
            android:layout_height="1000dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="Background Image"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/background2" />
```

I gave it specific height and widths, otherwise the background image is way too small, much smaller than its actual size.

Example of the two left individual images:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-7dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/digit5top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:src="@drawable/top" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/digit5bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bottom" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**How can I get my background image and individual tile images to appear the same size/proportion on all devices?**

Comment: Graphical View isn't reliable in these cases. Have you tried it on any real devices, or emulator?

Comment: Have you placed same size images inside of all drawables?

Comment: Yes, I have one real device to test on, working on getting more. Hard to know if I should adjust things perfectly on my device and then placement and sizing should look fine on others?

Comment: @Lokesh For low and medium I am using standard size. For high and extra high I am using double those sizes.

Comment: So based on the size of drawable images, related devices displayed images. Currently you used different sizes, by the reason they shown different sizes on different devices.

Comment: Which image you are able to show same size on all device, use same size in all drawables

Comment: @Lokesh I guess I missed the point of the different drawable sizes. So they all need to be the same pixel dimensions, just different dpi?

Comment: You could use the emulator to test on different devices. As far as I know I should be enough if you put the high res image in /drawable, then it will be scaled automatically to fit lower res devices. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @andysando I hope this is the case. Can someone confirm?